# Как хранить анекдоты в json а потом получать их на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Решил я такой написать бота, который будет мне скидывать смешные(и не очень) анекдоты, а не тут-то было
Решено было воспользоваться json

```
with open("Jokes.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    anek = random.choice(data["jokes"])
    print(anek)
```

Анекдоты(несмешные):
`{"jokes":["-Увидимся сегодня?\n-Я болею.\n-Так можно в аптеке посидеть...", "Самые яркие воспоминания начинаются со слов :' Зря, конечно, мы это делали...'"]}`

В итоге он мне выкидывал вот такое

> -РЈРІРёРґРёРјСЃСЏ СЃРµРіРѕРґРЅСЏ?
> -РЇ Р±РѕР»РµСЋ.
> -РўР°Рє РјРѕР¶РЅРѕ РІ Р°РїС‚РµРєРµ РїРѕСЃРёРґРµС‚СЊ...

Буду благодарен вариантам с json или альтернативам

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать кодировку. `encoding="utf8"`

```
import json
import random
with open("Jokes.json", encoding="utf8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    anek = random.choice(data["jokes"])
    print(anek)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, забыл о таком аргументе))